# How to target an element under an other element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors

I can click on a button (button A) and with some jquery it makes an image visible on this button at the exact same position (position:absolute).

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vinyl/eCCR6/)

I would like to click again on this button (button A) to hide the image but i don't know how because  the image is over the button.

I've found other solutions (more jquery or use an invisible image button) but i would like to find a more elegant way.

How can i target the button which is under the image ?

Jquery Code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#button').css('cursor', 'pointer');
    $('#button').click(function() {
        if ($('#image_1').css('visibility') == 'hidden') {
            $('#image_1').css('visibility', 'visible');
        } else {
            $('#image_1').css('visibility', 'hidden');
        }
    });
});
```

CSS :

```
#button
{
    width:100px;
    background-color:#666666;
    height:25px;
    position:absolute;
    left:10px;
    top:10px;
}

#image_1
{
    width:100px;
    background-color:#666666;
    height:25px;
    position:absolute;
    left:10px;
    top:10px;
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

html

```
<div id=main>
    <div id="button">
    </div>
    <div id="image_1">Hello World!
    </div>
</div><!-- main -->
```

@closure @Justin John @Jai @Robz @Adam @Happy Singh @Ross Dargan @Wouter de Kort @Viral Patel @Ruben Stolk
Thank you for all your interesting answers. It's difficult to choose because there are some really good ones. I've chosen Adam's answer because it's the simplest (juste use toglle jQuery and a css class). If you think your answer is better, please post your arguments here.

Comment: How can you click on a button you can't see? Surly you want to click on the img!?

Comment: The button is #button with background-color:#666666; You can see it. I've simplified the example but in my project there are 2 images (one is a button, one appears over the button after the click)

Comment: Your image has the same size of your button so your button is not reachable once the image is visible. That's the problem with your desing. Change that and you should be able to click the button.

Comment: you can trigger the click event of button on click of `#image_1` see the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I binded the click event to both the `#button` and the `#image` by adding the class `button` to them both; when you click either, it will show/hide the image.

Also if you use `display: none` instead of `visibility: hidden` you can use jQuery's [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/), which saves you a few lines of code.

see the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eCCR6/5/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.button').click(function() {
        $('#image_1').toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: I accept your answer because i think it's the simplest. But there are other nice answers. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

See the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/eCCR6/2/.

I have created the function like this, and bound to both:

```
function clickFn() {
    if ($('#image_1').css('visibility') == 'hidden') {
        $('#image_1').css('visibility', 'visible');
    } else {
        $('#image_1').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    }
}
```

Another model is to bind your event to the parent div `main`.

See the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/eCCR6/18/

Answer (score 1):

How about something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#button').css('cursor', 'pointer');
    $('#button').click(function() {
        $('#image_1').show();
    });

    $('#image_1').click(function() {
       $(this).hide();
    });
});​
```

Check this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/viralpatel/R5MVD/1/

Comment: The fiddle doesn't work but i see what you mean. I'm going to try.

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to put the image div inside your button div. You can also use the jQuery toggle function to show/hide the image.

```
<div id=main>
    <div id="button">
       <div id="image_1">Hello World!
       </div>    
    </div>
</div><!-- main -->    ​

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#button').css('cursor', 'pointer');
    $('#button').click(function() {
        $('#image_1').toggle();
    })
});​
```

Here is a fiddle that shows it: http://jsfiddle.net/jBaWN/2/

Answer (score 1):

This fiddle shows how it can be done easliy: http://jsfiddle.net/33aus/1/

Note I changed the image's css to display:none.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#button').css('cursor', 'pointer');
    $('#button').click(toggleVisiblity);
    $('#image_1').click(toggleVisiblity);
});
function toggleVisiblity()
{    
    $('#button').toggle();
    $('#image_1').toggle();
}​
```

Comment: Nice. I've tested it and It only works with display:none and not with visibility:hidden; correct ?

Comment: this method does as .toggle looks for display:none, and toggles that.

Answer (score 1):

See the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/eCCR6/8/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#button').css('cursor', 'pointer');
    $('#button').click(function() {
        if ($('#image_1').css('visibility') == 'hidden') {
            $('#image_1').css('visibility', 'visible');
        }
    });
    $('#image_1').click(function() {
        if ($('#image_1').css('visibility') == 'visible') {
            $('#image_1').css('visibility', 'hidden');
        }
    });


});
```

Answer (score 1):

just change your javascript to

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#button').css('cursor', 'pointer');
$('#button').click(function() {
    if ($('#image_1').css('visibility') == 'hidden') {
        $('#image_1').css('visibility', 'visible');
    } else {
        $('#image_1').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    }
});
$('#image_1').click(function(){
          $('#image_1').css('visibility', 'hidden');
});


});
```

Comment: It's ok. I've done this before. It works but i can see answers with only one function.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to trigger the button on mousedown on `img 1` try this one:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#button').css('cursor', 'pointer');
    $('#button').click(function() {
        if ($('#image_1').css('visibility') == 'hidden') {
            $('#image_1').css('visibility', 'visible');
        } else if ($('#image_1').css('visibility') == 'visible') {
            $('#image_1').css('visibility', 'hidden');
        }

        $('#image_1').mousedown(function(){
           $('#button').click();
        });
    });
});
```

Here we have done 1 else if check and trigger the button click on mousedown event on `#image_1`.

checkout the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eCCR6/16/

Answer (score 1):

You can also combine both selectors like this in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eCCR6/17/).

```
$('#button, #image_1').click(function() {
 // Your code 
});
```

Comment: Nice to use both selectors.

Answer (score 0):

Use the jquery .prev() or .next() function

Answer (score 0):

Instead of causing the image to become responsive to clicking (which does not work when there are multiple buttons below the image), you could make the image non-responsive to clicks using the `pointer-events` CSS property. It would look something like this:

```
#image_1
{
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eCCR6/31/

This will cause clicks to pass through the image directly to the button below.

The disadvantage to this method is that the image no longer responds to mouse movement, but in this case, that's okay.